# Filling a diagonal matrix based on selectors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]

[False, False, True, False, False, False]
```

The first list represent the row_number, column_number of the matrix. The second list represent the element value. How can I create an efficient loop(or other algorithm) so I end up with a 4 by 4 matrix:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy if you use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress

d = [(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]   
sel = [False, False, True, False, False, False]

res = [[0 if (j, i) not in compress(d, sel) else 1 for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
```

Yields:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Compress takes some data (`d` here) and some selectors (`sel` here) and retains the data that has the corresponding selector with a true value.

The list comprehension then creates the matrix and fills it with zeros or ones accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and editing my question! I add an extra line to turn the list back in matrix:
`np.array(res)`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `sparse` library from the `scipy` module for efficient sparse matrix manipulation. Here is how you would create the desired matrix:

```
from scipy import sparse
coo = [(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
data = [False, False, True, False, False, False]

m = sparse.coo_matrix((data,zip(*coo)), shape=(4,4))
print(m)
```

Note that there are [many](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) other sparse matrix formats (including diagonal) depending on what representation you find most appropriate to create and manipulate it.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works well. But I have to turn the original matrix to symmetric matrix. But somehow:
`m_symm = m+m.T' 
would not work.

Comment: That's because `m.T` doesn't exist, use `m.transpose()` instead. To find more information about how to use sparse matrices see the [official doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to actually be a numpy-like matrix? Seems to me you could do something like:

```
coords = [(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
values = [False, False, True, False, False, False]

DEFAULT_VALUE = 0

height, width = max(coords)[0], max(coords, key=lambda x_y:x_y[1])[1]
matrix = [[DEFAULT_VALUE for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
for coord, value in zip(coords, values):
    y, x = coord
    matrix[y][x] = value
```